# database when accessed in an activity which extends webview shows error

Tags: android

```
package com.pack.epubreader;
```

/* all the imports */

public abstract class EpubWebView extends WebView {
    private final static float FLING_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

```
/*
 * The book view will show
 */
public  static SQLiteDatabase db;
DatabaseManipulation dbManipulation = new DatabaseManipulation();
//MainActivity lastChapterAddress= new MainActivity(); 
MySQLiteHelper dbManager;

private Book mBook;


String lastPage;

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

/*
 * "root" page we're currently showing
 */
private Uri mCurrentResourceUri, extraUri, extraUri_start, extraUri_lastPos,extraUri_chapter ;

/*
 * Position of document
 */
private float mScrollY = 0.0f; 

public String sentFilename=null;

/*
 * Note that we're loading from a bookmark
 */
private boolean mScrollWhenPageLoaded = false;

/*
 * To speak the text
 */
private TextToSpeechWrapper mTtsWrapper;

/*
 * The page, as text
 */
private ArrayList<String> mText;

private WebViewClient mWebViewClient;

/*
 * Current line being spoken
 */
private int mTextLine;

/*
 * Pick an initial default
 */
private float mFlingMinDistance = 320;

public EpubWebView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public EpubWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, mGestureListener);
    WebSettings settings = getSettings();
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);        
    setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient = createWebViewClient());
}

/*
 * @ return Android version appropriate WebViewClient 
 */
abstract protected WebViewClient createWebViewClient();

public void testDataURL(AssetManager assetManager) {
    setBook(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

    // String resourceName = "content/calibre_title_page.html";
    // String resourceName = "content/074349881X__p__split_0.html";
    // gingerbreadLoadUrl(Book.resourceName2Url(resourceName));

    loadChapter(null);
} 


/*
 * Book to show
 */
public void setBook(String fileName) {
    //String Count=Intent.getExtra
    System.out.println(fileName+"  book going to load");
    sentFilename=fileName;

    // if book already loaded, don't load again
    if ((mBook == null) || !mBook.getFileName().equals(fileName)) {
        mBook = new Book(fileName);
    }
}






public Book getBook() {
    return mBook;
}

protected WebViewClient getWebViewClient() {
    return mWebViewClient;
}

/*
 * Chapter of book to show
 */
public void loadChapter(Uri resourceUri) 
{
    if (mBook != null) 
    {
        // if no chapter resourceName supplied, default to first one.
        if (resourceUri == null) 
        {

            resourceUri = mBook.firstChapter();
            extraUri=resourceUri;
            extraUri_start=resourceUri;
            String extra_uriStart=extraUri.toString();
            //String extraUri_start_str=resourceUri.toString();

            //dbManipulation.updatingBookdetails(sentFilename, extraUri_start); 
            //lastChapterAddress.findLastAddress(extraUri_start, sentFilename);
            System.out.println(sentFilename+"  name of book going to load first");
            System.out.println(extraUri_start+"  address of book going to load first");

            //db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", EpubWebView.this.MODE_PRIVATE,null); error here
            //db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);// and here
             try
             {



             System.out.println("BLOW FILE111");
             db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
             db.setLockingEnabled(true);
             db.setVersion(1);


             System.out.println("BLOW FILE222");

             ContentValues val=new ContentValues();
             val.put("bookpath",fileName );
             val.put("lastchapter", strAddress);
             db.update("Bookdetails", val, "bookpath="+fileName, null);
             System.out.println("BLOW FILE333");
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 System.out.println(e+"  errors happens");
             }
             finally
             {
                 db.close();
             }


            //dbManager.updateBook(sentFilename, extra_uriStart);




            System.out.println(sentFilename+"  name of book going to load");
           //(extraUri_start);

            System.out.println(resourceUri+"  actual Uri from top");
            String resuristr = resourceUri.toString();
            System.out.println(resuristr+"  actual string from top");
        }
        if (resourceUri != null) 
        {
            if(extraUri==null)
            {
                extraUri=resourceUri;
            }
            String extraUristr=extraUri.toString();
            //extraUristr=extraUristr.substring(extraUristr.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            //extraUristr= extraUristr.substring(8);
            int p=extraUristr.lastIndexOf("/");
             extraUristr=extraUristr.substring(0,p);
            System.out.println(extraUristr+" cutted string_1");

            String extraUri2=resourceUri.toString();
            int q=extraUri2.lastIndexOf("/");
            extraUri2=extraUri2.substring(q);
            extraUri2=extraUristr+extraUri2;
            System.out.println(extraUri2+" Joined Uri  string_2");

            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(extraUri2);
            System.out.println(myUri+"--> Joined Uri ");
            resourceUri= myUri;
            System.out.println(resourceUri+"actual string");
            mCurrentResourceUri = resourceUri;
            // prevent cache, because WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE doesn't always work.
            clearCache(false);
            LoadUri(resourceUri);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * @ return load contents of URI into WebView,
 *   implementation is android version dependent 
 */
protected abstract void LoadUri(Uri uri);

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) ||
         super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // if no book, nothing to do
        if (mBook == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // also ignore swipes that are vertical, too slow, or too short.
        float deltaX = event2.getX() - event1.getX();
        float deltaY = event2.getY() - event1.getY();

        if ((Math.abs(deltaX) < Math.abs(deltaY))
                || (Math.abs(deltaX) < mFlingMinDistance)
                || (Math.abs(velocityX) < FLING_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                return changeChapter(mBook.nextResource(mCurrentResourceUri));
            } else {
                return changeChapter(mBook.previousResource(mCurrentResourceUri));
            }
        }
    }
};

private boolean changeChapter(Uri resourceUri) {
    if (resourceUri != null) {
        loadChapter(resourceUri);
        System.out.println(resourceUri+ "  next chapter uri");
        return true;
    } else {
        Utility.showToast(getContext(), R.string.end_of_book);
        return false;
    }
}



/*
 * Store current view into bookmark
 */
public Bookmark getBookmark() {
    if ((mBook != null) && (mCurrentResourceUri != null)) { 
        float contentHeight = (float)getContentHeight();
        contentHeight = (contentHeight == 0.0f) ? 0.0f : getScrollY() / contentHeight; 
        return new Bookmark (
            mBook.getFileName(),
            mCurrentResourceUri,
            contentHeight
        );
    }
    return null;
}

public void gotoBookmark(Bookmark bookmark) {
    if (!bookmark.isEmpty()) {
        mScrollY = bookmark.mScrollY;

        // get notify when content height is available, for setting Y scroll position
        mScrollWhenPageLoaded = true;
        setBook(bookmark.getFileName());
        loadChapter(bookmark.getResourceUri());
    }
}

public void speak(TextToSpeechWrapper ttsWrapper) {
    mTtsWrapper = ttsWrapper;
    if ((mBook != null) && (mCurrentResourceUri != null)) {
        mText = new ArrayList<String>();
        XmlUtil.parseXmlResource(
                mBook.fetch(mCurrentResourceUri).getData(), 
                new XhtmlToText(mText), null);
        mTextLine = 0;
        mTtsWrapper.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(mCompletedListener);
        if (0 < mText.size()) {
            mTtsWrapper.speak(mText.get(0));
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Send next piece of text to Text to speech
 */
private TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener mCompletedListener = 
        new TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
        if (mTextLine < mText.size() - 1) {
            mTtsWrapper.speak(mText.get(++mTextLine));
        }
    }

};

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mFlingMinDistance = w / 2;
}

/*
 * Called when page is loaded,
 * if we're scrolling to a bookmark, we need to set the
 * page size listener here.  Otherwise it can be called
 * for pages other than the one we're interested in 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void onPageLoaded() {
    if (mScrollWhenPageLoaded) {
        setPictureListener(mPictureListener);
        mScrollWhenPageLoaded = false;
    }
}

/*
 * Need to wait until view has figured out how big web page is
 * Otherwise, we can't scroll to last position because 
 * getContentHeight() returns 0.
 * At current time, there is no replacement for PictureListener 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private PictureListener mPictureListener = new PictureListener() {
    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
        // stop listening 
        setPictureListener(null);

        scrollTo(0, (int)(getContentHeight() * mScrollY));
        mScrollY = 0.0f;
    }
};
```

}

Error is showing where i have mentioned why is this happening?
please help i am stuck here for two days

Comment: Can you provide us logcat??

Comment: error occurs in the page itself, its is like this
the method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type EpuWebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change here.

```
Context ctx;

public EpubWebView(Context context) {
  this(context, null);
  this.ctx = context;
}

public EpubWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
 super(context, attrs);
  this.ctx = context;
  mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, mGestureListener);
  WebSettings settings = getSettings();
  settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);        
 setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient = createWebViewClient());
}
```

Now change here

```
db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", EpubWebView.this.MODE_PRIVATE,null); 
db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
```

Comment: Good One. Glad to help you!!